# Symfony translation ignores curly braces in parameters

Tags: php, symfony, translation, xliff

When using the symfony translation module to translate a piece of code it seems that symfony is ignoring the curly braces.

```
 <trans-unit id="test">
    <source>test<source>
    <target>
        test {test}
    </target>
</trans-unit>
```

When using the following `Translator` config.

```
$translator = new Translator("en");
$translator->addLoader('xlf', new XliffFileLoader());
$translator->addResource('xlf', 'translations/messages+intl-icu.en.xlf', 'en');
$translator->setFallbackLocales(["en"]);

$message = $translator->trans("test", ["test" => "error"], null, "en");
```

Produces the following translation: `error {error}` while I would expect `test error`

Is this an error in my config somewhere or did I misunderstand how the replacement should take place?

My symfony versions are as follows.

```
"symfony/translation": "v5.0.2",
"symfony/config": "v5.0.2"
```

According to the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html)

`Everything within the curly braces ({...}) is processed by the formatter and replaced by its placeholder:`

Is this an error in Symfony or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and asked : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36461

Answer : you need to pass `['{test}' => 'error']` as the parameters array, including the curly braces in the key string.

Comment: Shame it doesn't say so in the documentation. I'll accept even if it isn't the solution I had hoped for.